# Error when downloading .tif image from url in R: I only get a corrupted small file

Tags: r, download, tiff

I have been trying to download a tif file from an URL, but what I can get is only a small (100kb) object that, instead, should be a 30mb raster. I expected this to be straightforward, but have been absolutely unable to identify where things go wrong (the other similar questions I have found here are from non-reproductible datasets).

My code is the following:

```
 url <- "https://storage.cloud.google.com/mapbiomas-public/COLECAO/5/DOWNLOADS/COLECOES/ANUAL/PAMPA/PAMPA-1985.tif"
    file <- basename(url)
    download.file(url, file,mode = "wb")
```

The general message I get is:

```
trying the URL 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/mapbiomas-public/COLECAO/5/DOWNLOADS/COLECOES/ANUAL/PAMPA/PAMPA-1985.tif'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length unknown
downloaded 98 KB
```

Comment: If you are trying to debug this, why include `quiet = T`???  Show us the error messages you're getting (and hiding).

Comment: There is no error:
`trying the URL 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/mapbiomas-public/COLECAO/5/DOWNLOADS/COLECOES/ANUAL/PAMPA/PAMPA-1985.tif'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length unknown
downloaded 98 KB`

Comment: When I download that file, I just get a web page saying there's no such file, but including a bunch of Javascript code.  I suspect the Javascript needs to execute to get the TIF you want.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I am very unfamiliar with javascript, so I will try to make something that accesses the page under auto download in my browser.